# Change value of Variable after i click on another radio input

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with changing the value of a variable after checking another radio input.
I was looking for this on the whole internet, but I was not able to find something like this.
I just want to VAR radio_value value when i click on another radio input.

MY HTML:

```
<div class="col pl-3">
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="awards_duration" value="D-T1-1M">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="duration">
            1 Month - 2€
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="awards_duration" value="D-T1-3M" checked>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="duration">
            3 Months - 3€
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

My JS:

```
var user_id = 'UserID';
var item_price = '2', item_name = 'Donation - Tier 1 (1 Month)', item_id = 'D-T1-1M';

var radio_value = document.querySelector('input[name="awards_duration"]:checked').value;

if(radio_value === 'D-T1-1M') {
    var item_price  = '2';
    var item_name   = 'Donation - Tier 1 (1 Month)';
    var item_id     = 'D-T1-1M';
    console.log(item_price);
};
if(radio_value === 'D-T1-3M') {
    var item_price  = '4.5';
    var item_name   = 'Donation - Tier 1 (3 Months)';
    var item_id     = 'D-T1-3M';
    console.log(item_price);
};
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

add an event handler to each radio button

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[name="awards_duration"]').forEach(input =>{
  input.addEventListener("change", () => {
    var radio_value = document.querySelector('input[name="awards_duration"]:checked').value;
    // radio button changed magic here
  })
});
```

Comment: check the console, maybe there is an error there

Answer (score 0):

You can use onclick. In the JS, type:

```
function changeValue() {
   var radio_value = document.querySelector('input[name="awards_duration"]:checked').value;
}
```

Then, in each  element, add this into it:

```
onclick="changeValue()"
```

So the first input would be like:

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="awards_duration" value="D-T1-1M" onclick="changeValue()">
```

Sorry if I'm incorrect or misunderstood your question.